# Combine GoogleSheets functions

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, google-docs, google-spreadsheets

I'm trying to combine multiple functions into one formula in GoogleSheets spreadsheet.

I've tried learning more from Google's Help center and through YouTube but didn't came to satisfactory result.

Anyways, I have these:

---

- **A:** *Column with some of keywords*
- **B:** *Column where I replace **whitespace** character with **+** sign:* **=REGEXREPLACE(A2, " ", "+")**
- **C:** *Column to generate Google search query URL with previously generated data:* 
  **=CONCATENATE("https://www.google.com/search?q=intitle:", """"&B2&"""" )**

---

Is there a way for **C** column to take **A** column as a **data input** without need for **B** column to exist, in form of an oneliner formula which combines both functions?

Result should look like this:
**https://www.google.rs/search?q=intitle:example+keyword**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. You can use nested functions in spreadsheet formulas in GoogleSheets, Excel, or pretty much any spreadsheet application. Just replace `B2` in the formula with the formula used to generate the value in B2.

```
=CONCATENATE("https://www.google.com/search?q=intitle:", """"&REGEXREPLACE(A2, " ", "+")&"""" )
```

Comment: Unbelievable, it worked now even though I tried and it didn't. This is what i came up with: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=1w5wFLhY
I tried getting amount of search results for bunch of keywords and their search queries. Thanks man, you saved the day!